# How to build Docker with env file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm stuck with env file during docker build.

I'm trying to build docker image for my ruby project which uses environment variables for a number of reasons.
One of the reason is checking either database is available or not(Using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection`), and based on that going to create/update a database with some master data.

I can use env file during docker run via `docker run --env-file='.env'` command.

But I want to use those ENV variables during my docker build.

Can anyone help me out with this situations?

Comment: I ran into this problem and there is no elegant way around this. I wish, docker provided such a feature during build stage.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

You can add `ENV myvariable myvalue` in your Dockerfile.
Check the [docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) doc.

Comment: Thank you for reply.
If I follow approach which you suggested, then I have to use multiple `ENV myvariable myvale` statements right?
Just need to confirm because I have 5 to 6 different ENV variables.
Is there any work-around through which I can pass complete ENV file?

Comment: Yes you have to use multiple ENV.

Comment: As of 2022, you can use a single `ENV` command to set multiple environment variables. Besides a slightly more brief syntax, you also get the benefit of creating only a single layer with this approach. Simply write `ENV KEY=value \` then on a new line, tab in once, and continue with `KEY_TWO=value_two` etc

Answer (score 20):

If you are using docker-compose (which now comes bundled with Docker), *.env* is the default filename for the file that contains variables that are made available to the **parser** for the *docker-compose.yml* file ONLY, and not to the build process or container environment variables.

Using the `--env-file` command line argument or setting the `env_file` variable in your *docker-compose.yml* file will identify the file from which to load variables into the **container environment** (and not the build process). You can run `set` from a shell in your running container to view the environment variables that are loaded.

It is a common antipattern to set `env_file=.env` in *docker-compose.yml* which is a very confusing thing to do as it makes the *.env* file provide both variables to the *docker-compose.yml* **parser** AND the running **container environment** - it is almost certainly the reason that you are reading this.

If you want variables in your *.env* to be available to the **build process**, i.e. you want to use them in your *Dockerfile*, then you will need to explicitly set them in *docker-compose.yml* AND you will need to load them at the top of your *Dockerfile*. This example shows the syntax to use in *.env*, *docker-compose.yml*, and *Dockerfile*:

```
# This excerpt is from .env
# ...
# The quotes here are important if you have any special 
# characters and want them to work on mac, pc and linux:
ARG_1="value of first argument"
ARG_2="value of second argument"
ARG_3="value of third argument"
# ...
```

```
# This excerpt is from docker-compose.yml
# ...
# env_file (.env.staging) is loaded in the container at runtime:
    env_file:
      - .env.staging
# ...
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: docker/app/Dockerfile
# The following will let you use ${ARG_x} during your build in docker/app/Dockerfile
      args:
        ARG_1: ${ARG_1}
        ARG_2: ${ARG_2}
        ARG_3: ${ARG_3}
# ...
```

```
# This excerpt is from /docker/app/Dockerfile
FROM somerepo/someimage:ver as something
# Import variables from docker-compose.yml:
ARG ARG_1=$ARG_1
ARG ARG_2=$ARG_2
ARG ARG_3=$ARG_3
# ...
# Now you can use ${ARG_1}, ${ARG_2} etc to reference values from your .env file
# ...
```

Comment: This works flawlessly, little bit hacky, but exactly what I was looking for. Great explanation!!

Comment: I'd agree that it's hacky, sadly sort of par for the course with Docker (it was designed to work this way in this case)

Comment: I've thought way to long on this topic then I should've lol. It makes sense. The builder doesn't use environment variables. Those environment variables are only accessible at container runtime. not at build runtime. Docker still reads the environment file before layering. But it requires build arguments in those layers instead of environment variables. (since the environment is not running at build time), I think I get the gist : )

Comment: @YetAnotherDuck this is a good summary!

Answer (score 13):

You can also set build environment variables with `--build-arg`. Example on [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables-build-arg)

As you can see, it is an equivalent to `docker run --env`, there isn't one for `--env-file`

Answer (score 9):

I have the same issue, honestly `--build-arg` isn't optimal when you have a lot of variables.
instead you can set a loop for them:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t IMAGE:TAG $(for i in `cat .env`; do out+="--build-arg $i " ; done; echo $out;out="") .
```

To enhance this, consider the following approach if your `.env` file contains empty lines and comments (lines starting with #) that should be ignored:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t IMAGE:TAG $(for i in $(grep -vE '^#|^$' .env); do out+="--build-arg $i " ; done; echo $out;out="") .
```

The `grep -vE '^#|^$'` command filters out the invalid lines.

Comment: This is super interesting, but one thing to keep in mind is when you use build arguments, the values will be cached in the intermediate images produced during the build process. This could potentially leak sensitive data. Works great for checking if DB is up, but not suitable for any passwords/secrets.

Answer (score 4):

I had the case that I needed a variable inside an sed command. I've used the following:

```
RUN source config.env; sed -i -r "s/^url=.*/url=${MONGODB_SERVER}/" /app/module/module.ini
```

The variable availability is limited to that specific command, but that was sufficient for me.

Answer (score 0):

What I've read from others says that there is no "docker build --env-file...." option/apparatus.  As such, this situation makes a good argument for shifting more of the content of the dockerfile to a shell script that the dockerfile simply copies and runs, as you can source the .env file that way.

You an also source the .env file before running build using the --build-arg flag.  I've shown the combination of both ways below.

dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:latest

ARG myTestVarArg
ENV myTestVar $myTestVarArg    #takes the command line argument and makes it an env var

COPY variables.env .
RUN source variables.env && echo Foo $copyFileTest  #outputs Foo Bar
COPY greetings.sh .
RUN chmod +x /greetings.sh
RUN /greetings.sh               #outputs:  Hello World  and  Foo Bar

RUN echo $copyFileTest          #does not work, outputs nothing

RUN rm variables.env
```

greetings.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Hello $myTestVar

source variables.env
echo Foo $copyFileTest
```

variables.env

```
export myTestVariable="World"
export copyFileTest="Bar"
```

command line arguments

```
source variables.env
docker build --no-cache -t variabletest:0.01 --build-arg myTestVarArg=$myTestVariable .
```